# ImageMagick changes colors when converting PDF to images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am converting various PDFs uploaded by end users into images using following command

```
-density 140 -limit memory 64MB -limit map 128MB [pdffile] page.png
```

Here is the result. On the right we have original PDF and on the left output image. As you can see the colors are quite noticeably different.

What could be causing this and how fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try following command:

```
-density 140 -limit memory 64MB -limit map 128MB -colorspace RGB [pdffile] page.png
```

Comment: In case that doesn't work for you, try `sRGB` instead of `RGB`.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** I later discovered that ImageMagick can do it fine, I just needed to use `-colorspace sRGB`

My final command was:

```
convert -density 560 -limit memory 64MB -limit map 128MB \
        -colorspace sRGB [pdffile] -scale 25% page.png
```

The oversampling and scaling down was to counter the poor anti-aliasing mentioned below.

Before I discovered that, here was my earlier solution...

---

In my case the colors produced by ImageMagick's `convert` were oversaturated, quite like those in the question.  I was trying to convert [this file](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/visions-of-the-future/pdf/grand_tour.pdf) using IM 6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.

- `-resample 100` made no difference.
- `-colorspace RGB` seemed to produce more accurate saturations, but the entire image was darker than it should have been.

Curiously, [this suggestion](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8756#p31908) to use GhostScript instead of ImageMagick for the conversion, produced very close to the correct colors:

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=png16m -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
      -sOutputFile=page.png -r200 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE [pdffile]
```

(The original suggestion passed the `-dUseCIEColor` option, but in my case this appeared to reduce the gamma: light pixels were fine, but the dark pixels were too dark, so I removed it.)

After that, the only thing that bothered me was that the **anti-aliasing/edges were a little off** in places (especially visible on curves passing 45 degrees).  To improve that, I created the output at four times the required resolution, and then scaled down afterwards, rendering those errors almost imperceptible.  Note that I had to use ImageMagick's `-scale` for this, and **not** `-geometry` or `-resize`, in order to avoid [bicubic ringing effects](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14707/scaling-down-a-raster-image/28868#28868).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-resample` option:

```
-density 140 -resample 100 -limit memory 64MB -limit map 128MB [pdffile] page.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Source MuPDF util mutool retains color and size using default parameters below
you need though to list the pages separated by a comma at the end of the command.

mutool draw -o draw%d.png abook.pdf 1,2

Otherwise if using Linux try Windows for better colorspace RGB interpretation when using imagemagick's convert.

Answer (score -1):

The following images show how anti-aliasing improves if you sample at a higher resolution and then scale down.

Although 1120 was slightly better quality than 560, it took a long time to convert, so I would probably choose 560 for a good time:quality trade-off.

`-colorspace sRGB -density 140`

[image]

`-colorspace sRGB -density 280 -scale 50%`

[image]

`-colorspace sRGB -density 420 -scale 33.3333%`

[image]

`-colorspace sRGB -density 560 -scale 25%`

[image]

`-colorspace sRGB -density 1120 -scale 12.5%`

[image]

(It is easier to see the difference if you download the last two images and flip between them in your favourite image viewer.  Or scroll up this list of images, instead of down.  You should seem them becoming progressively uglier.)